# ng-model not updating inside Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-modal

ng-model which i am assigning is controller can be seen inside modal.But when i am updating the data inside the modal,the $scope variable is not updating.
Also dropdown is not working whose value i have defined in my controller.
Do i need to make changes in directive.

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Modal example</h1>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button>

  <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">

      <div>
          <select ng-model="client" ng-change="changeClient()" ng-options="item in clientList">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"  id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="buttonClicked()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

  </modal>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER CODE

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.email="hello@abc.com";
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
    $scope.buttonClicked=function(){
    alert("hello1");
    alert($scope.email);
    alert($scope.client);
    }

    $scope.clientList=["300","600","900"]
    $scope.client=$scope.clientList[0];
    $scope.changeClient = function() {
            selectedValue=$scope.client;
           alert(selectedValue);
         };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Have a Look-[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/RLQhh/2292/)

Answer (score 11):

you should use:

```
$parent.email

<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/RLQhh/2299/)

Comment: Thanx man...working fine for email but the dropdown is still a problem...any idea how to handle that?

Comment: @RHUL have you checked the fiddle? the dropdown seems worked well.

Answer (score 2):

As huan feng said, you can use '$parent' because directive has it's own isolated scope. For your 'select' the simplest solution is to use something like that:

```
<select ng-model="$parent.client" ng-change="changeClient()" ng-options="item for item in clientList">
```

**But**, it could be better to use your model in a little bit different way. Create your 'clientInfo' object with email and clien as properties. 
JS:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clientInfo = {};

    $scope.clientInfo.email="hello@abc.com";
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
    $scope.buttonClicked=function(){
    alert("hello1");
    alert($scope.clientInfo.email);
    alert($scope.clientInfo.client);
    }

    $scope.clientList=["300","600","900"]
    $scope.clientInfo.client = $scope.clientList[0]; 

    $scope.changeClient = function() {
            selectedValue=$scope.clientInfo.client;
           alert(selectedValue);
         };
  });
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Modal example</h1>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button>

  <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">

      <div>
          <select ng-model="clientInfo.client" ng-change="changeClient()" ng-options="item for item in clientList">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="clientInfo.email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"  id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="buttonClicked()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

  </modal>
</div>
```

Comment: @huanfeng, I've updated my answer seconds ago, maybe it would be interesting for you too :)